# Stop duplicate mouse over detection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup that is executed on mouseover with jquery.

Within that function I have a second delay before the popup displays using settimeout

Problem is if in that second they mouse over multiple times then multiple popups are triggered.

```
$('#div').mouseover(function() {setTimeout("popup()",1000);});
```

What I need to do is disable the detection and then re enable it in popup().

How might I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) with a [`clearTimeout()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), like this:

```
$('#div').hover(function() {
  $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(popup, 1000)); 
}, function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
});
```

This clears the timeout you're setting if the mouse leaves, you'll have to stay on the element for a full second for the popup to trigger.  We're just using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) on the element to store the timer ID (so we know what to clear).  The other change is to not pass a string to `setTimeout()` but rather a reference directly to the function.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this

```
(function(){
    var popup_timer = 0;
    $('#div').mouseover(function() { 
        clearTimeout(popup_timer);
        popup_timer = setTimeout("popup()",1000);
    });
});
```

EDIT updated code, clearTimeout added, wrapped

Comment: I suggest wrapping that whole thing in an anonymous function and using `var` on `popup_timer`.  Be nice to your global scope